# Wicked_pdf page width in multipage pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

Cheers! I'm using wicked_pdf to generate pdf docs from views:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render_to_string(
    :layout => "pdf_report.haml",
    :handlers => [:haml],
    :formats => [:pdf, :haml],
    :orientation => 'Landscape',
    :encoding => "utf8",
    :page_width => '2000',
    :dpi => '300'
  )
)
```

It's all ok, if pdf has one page:

[image]

But if pdf doc has more than one page, then width of the page is broken:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your "only has one page" scenario with the code you posted, however there is a problem with the options you are passing. They aren't even getting to `wkhtmltopdf`, so it is probably deciding *for you* what kind of options to use.

`render_to_string` will silently discard any options it doesn't understand, but is not part of `wicked_pdf`.

`pdf_from_string` takes two params, the first being the string to pdf-ify, the second is a hash of pdf options from the README.

I've added your issue to the wicked_pdf_issues project here to reproduce and debug it:

https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/commit/b722e8a06c42e1f2bcbb98281915d1e94b4fe2c9

You should get the results you are looking for by changing your code to something like this:

```
string = render_to_string(
  template: 'pages/issue_330',
  formats: [:pdf],
  handlers: [:erb]
)
options = {
  orientation: 'Landscape',
  page_width: '2000',
  dpi: '300'
}
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(string, options)
```